# leaflet-draw error: TypeError: can't access property "falseFn", L.Util is undefined

Tags: firefox, next.js, leaflet, leaflet.draw, react-leaflet-v3

Am getting the error `TypeError: can't access property "falseFn", L.Util is undefined` when using react-leaflet v3.2.0, NextJs v12.1.6, leaflet v1.7.1 and leaflet-draw v1.0.4. The issue is visible on Firefox browser when you run in production. The error occurs in the following code:

```
function cI(b, a, g, e) {
    var f = a + V(g) + (e ? '_' + V(e) : '');
    if (b[cF] && b[cF][f]) return this;
    var d = function (a) {
      return g.call(e || b, a || window.event)
    },
    h = d;
    !c.touchNative && c.pointer && 0 === a.indexOf('touch') ? d = function (c, a, b) {
      return ('touchstart' === a && (cy || (document.addEventListener(bd, cz, !0), document.addEventListener(be, cA, !0), document.addEventListener(bf, cB, !0), document.addEventListener(bg, cB, !0), cy = !0)), cw[a]) ? (b = cw[a].bind(this, b), c.addEventListener(cv[a], b, !1), b) : (console.warn('wrong event specified:', a), L.Util.falseFn) 
    }(b, a, d) : c.touch && 'dblclick' === a ? d = function (a, b) {
      a.addEventListener('dblclick', b);
      var d,
      e = 0;
      function c(a) {
        if (1 !== a.detail) {
          d = a.detail;
          return
        }
        if ('mouse' !== a.pointerType && (!a.sourceCapabilities || a.sourceCapabilities.firesTouchEvents)) {
          var c = Date.now();
          c - e <= 200 ? 2 == ++d && b(function (c) {
            var b,
            d,
            a = {
            };
            for (d in c) b = c[d],
            a[d] = b && b.bind ? b.bind(c) : b;
            return c = a,
            a.type = 'dblclick',
            a.detail = 2,
            a.isTrusted = !1,
            a._simulated = !0,
            a
          }(a)) : d = 1,
          e = c
        }
      }
      return a.addEventListener('click', c),
      {
        dblclick: b,
        simDblclick: c
      }
    }(b, d) : 'addEventListener' in b ? 'touchstart' === a || 'touchmove' === a || 'wheel' === a || 'mousewheel' === a ? b.addEventListener(cH[a] || a, d, !!c.passiveEvents && {
      passive: !1
    }) : 'mouseenter' === a || 'mouseleave' === a ? (d = function (a) {
      bN(b, a = a || window.event) && h(a)
    }, b.addEventListener(cH[a], d, !1)) : b.addEventListener(a, h, !1) : b.attachEvent('on' + a, d),
    b[cF] = b[cF] || {
    },
    b[cF][f] = d
  }
```

Comment: It also happens in Safari browser

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by loading a lower version of leaflet (v1.3.1) on the component that has leaflet-draw.